# Partition has a blank slice

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am just starting out with the [d3 library](http://d3js.org/) and want to achieve what is called a **[Bilevel Partition](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371)**.

So I copied the code from the page and structured my JSON file to have the exact same structure as the JSON file used on the example page. So [my JSON file](http://pastebin.com/jKtzvpqP) also has the keys (e.g. `name` and `children`).

All seems to work until I click to navigate to the 2nd level, then all of a sudden I see that a slice is missing!

Here is a [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/7ftfloPl1m65) of what I mean. Also when I click the centre, it does not navigate back to the 1st level and after debugging I can see that the fault is the missing slice! The error I get in the chrome console is:

[image: console error]

It occurs on `line 767` in the uncompressed `d3.js`.

Why am I getting this error and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the reason was that I had a child repeated in my original data set!

```
"children" : [
{
    "name": "Citrus",
    "children": [
        {
            "Name": "Oranges",
            "size": 60
        },
        {
            "Name": "Lemons",
            "size": 35
        },
        {
            "Name": "Limes",
            "size": 30
        },
        {
            "Name": "Limes",
            "size": 40
        }
    ]
},
```

Once I fixed that, all was good.